# Making a histogram in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to make a histogram using the data given in `survey` below.

```
#represents the "information" (the summarized data)
ranking = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
survey = [1,5,3,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,4,5,1,7]

for i in range(len(survey)):
    ranking[survey[i]]+=1

#create histogram
print("\nCreating a histogram from values: ")
print("%3s %5s %7s"%("Element", "Value", "Histogram"))
for i in range(len(ranking)):
    print("%7d %5d %-s"%(i+1, ranking[i+1], "*" * ranking[i+1]))
```

Here is exactly what the shell displays when I run my code:

```
Creating a histogram from values: 
Element Value Histogram
      1     7 *******
      2     2 **
      3     2 **
      4     2 **
      5     2 **
      6     0 
      7     1 *
      8     0 
      9     0 
     10     0 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\folder\file23.py", line 17, in <module>
    print("%7d %5d %-s"%(i+1, ranking[i+1], "*" * ranking[i+1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My expected output is the above thing just without the traceback.

The shell is displaying the right thing, I'm just unsure of the error message. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index `i` is incremented up to `len(ranking)-1`, which is the last valid index in `ranking`, but you're trying to access `ranking[i+1]`, hence the `IndexError`.

Fix:

```
for i in range(len(ranking)-1):
```

Answer (score 1):

When `i` reaches its highest value, `len(ranking) - 1`, your use of `ranking[i+1]` **is** clearly "out of range"!  Use `range(len(ranking) - 1` in the `for` loop to avoid the error.

The counting can be simplified, too:

```
import collections
ranking = collections.Counter(survey)

for i in range(min(ranking), max(ranking)+1):
    print("%7d %5d %-s"%(i, ranking[i], "*" * ranking[i]))
```

Here you need `min` and `max` because `Counter` is mapping-like, not sequence-like.  But it will still work fine (and you **can** use `range(0, max(ranking)+1)` if you prefer!-)

Comment: Thank you, however I am not sure how to use counter.

Comment: @asdfmovie, just index it!  Let me edit the A to expand, but it's really trivial.